# Creating a PowerScript module using scripts in multiple files

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2012

I'm going to work on a large power script project. I want to create an architecture for my files and make it more maintainable.

I want to put each function in a separate `ps1` file, so I can manage them separately.

For example, consider I want to have 2 `ps1` files call it: `FunctionA`, `FunctionB`.

Then I want to have a `MyFunctions.psm1` which is an aggregation of those 2 functions.

I don't want to write the functions directly in the `psm1` file. I want write functions separately in the files, then aggregate them in the module.

The aggregation operation is something like building a project.

My utopia is a Visual Studio Project which I can add `ps1` files in it, then, when I build the project a `psm1` file would be generated.

I found a [CodePlex project](http://powerguivsx.codeplex.com/) (PowerGUI) which is a Visual Studio Extension that adds a PowerShell Project Template.

But, unfortunately, it doesn't seem to have this `psm1` auto generating.

**Question 1:** Is there any way to add this feature to the project, For example, adding something to `Build Events`.

**Question 2:** Is there another way of creating a `psm1` file from `ps1` files. Something like a `Aggregate-Functions` cmdlet or function!?

Comment: Don't you think that having one file per function is a logistical nightmare, unless your functions are extremely complex and long (which then become a maintenance nightmare ...)?

Comment: @DavidBrabant Having them in a Visual Studio Project makes it sensible. Each file can be checked-in and checked-out. So multiple developers can work concurrently. So why would it be a nightmare!? Maybe aggregating `Modules` into a final `Module` would be a better question?

Comment: @DavidBrabant - which would you rather have, thousands of lines of code to sift through, or separate files that contain exactly and only what they express to contain?  I started out with the former, it was an absolute mess.  I now use the former and it is incredibly easy to work with.  I suppose it's subjective to a point, and dependent upon the tooling and experience of the end user?

Comment: @CookieMonster: "or separate files that contain exactly and only what they express to contain". Yes, that's my point: *exactly* and *only* what they express to contain. Is *one* function that granularity? I serioulsy doubt it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very easy to do with dot-sourcing in psm1. E.g. in the module directory we have:

func1.ps1

```
function func1 {
    'Hello from func1'
}
```

func2.ps1

```
function func2 {
    'Hello from func2'
}
```

test.psm1

```
. $PSScriptRoot\func1.ps1
. $PSScriptRoot\func2.ps1
```

This is it, the module is ready. Now this code imports the module and tests `func1` and `func2`:

```
Import-Module .\test.psm1
func1
func2
```

Output:

```
Hello from func1
Hello from func2
```

Comment: This is good advice.  You can also avoid hard coding the file names and use PowerShell to obtain them (e.g. Get-ChildItem, loop, try to load the file, catch errors).  Maybe have a separate spot for private functions to make it easy to differentiate if you use Export-ModuleMember.  Cheers!